# Trying to get property 'pivot' of non-object (Laravel 7 - Accessors)

Tags: laravel, pivot-table, laravel-7, accessor

I have used Laravel 7 for my project. This project has a many-to-many relationship between two tables named "orders" and "products." The following is my code for the "order" model.

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product')
        ->withPivot('quantity', 'unit_discount', 'unit_price');
}

public function getTotalGrossPriceAttribute()
{
    $totalGrossPrice = 0;
    foreach ($this->products as $product) {
        $totalGrossPrice += ($product->pivot->quantity *
            ($product->pivot->unit_discount + $product->pivot->unit_price));
    }
    
    return $totalGrossPrice;
}
```

But unfortunately, it brings up this error "Trying to get property 'pivot' of non-object"! I would be grateful if to tell me what is exactly wrong with my code.

Comment: Try - >pivot()  instead of - >pivot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately I found a solution in the end. I changed this piece of code

```
foreach ($this->products as $product)
```

with this one

```
foreach ($this->products()->get() as $product)
```

and now it works well.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access pivot, but it's not present in the collection. Dump (dd) $this->products, for every collection the pivot is missing. You can't do like that directly without presence of Order model.

So, instead of $this->products, try calling $order->products.

BTW, you can create another model as Pivot for ProductOrder.

```php
<?php
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class ProductOrder extends Pivot
{
    //
}
```